# How to resize image to be uploaded

Tags: php, image, image-resizing

I have a form to upload images, but I would like to change the image aspect ratio such that it is a square without cropping any of the image.

e.g if the image is 500px by 600px, the image will be resized to 500px by 500px without having 100px cropped out.

Here is the upload form:

```
$target_dir = "Uploads/";
$name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$name = md5($name);
$name = $name . uniqid($name);
$path = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$name = $name.".".$ext;
$target_file = $target_dir . $name;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

$SQL = "INSERT INTO Posts (image) VALUES ('$target_file')";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
}
```

This all works brilliantly, but I'm wondering if there is a little bit of code I can implement to do the resize before it is sent to the directory.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a library function to scale the image.  For example, [Imagick::scaleImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.scaleimage.php).

Consider keeping the aspect ratio the same and simply reducing the image to within the required bounds (like the linked scaleImage does).